# SessionFactory calling openSession throws noSuchMethoderror exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, spring-batch

I am using **hibernate 3.2.5.GA**, when invoking `openSession` of `SessionFactory`, it returns `Session` object of type `org.hibernate.classic.Session` :

```
public org.hibernate.classic.Session openSession() throws HibernateException;
```

I am also using **Spring Batch 2.2.7.RELEASE**, when setting `SessionFacotry` in `HibernateItemReaderHelper`, an exception is thrown when `openSession` in invoked because it expects `Session` of Type : `org.hibernate.Session`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
```

Anyone knows a solution to this?

P.S. I can not upgrade the **Hibernate**.

Answer (score 1):

It is odd that they use the org.hibernate.classic.Session implementation in the SessionFactory even after version 3 up to version 4 seeing how both are available ( org.hibernate.classic.Session and org.hibernate.Session) after version 3. As you may know spring classic is used for compatibility with hibernate 2.1, it is deprecated as of hibernate 3.

#### Advice

You **should not** be using **HibernateItemReaderHelper** as it is a spring internal class. It's introduced in Spring Batch 2.2.7.

#### Solution

I've looked at the code of a couple of all the available [item readers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/reference/html/listOfReadersAndWriters.html#itemReadersAppendix) but they used the new org.hibernate.Session.
There is no way getting around it in this version.

- If you cannot change the hibernate version, change the Spring Batch version to an earlier one and choose one of it's item readers.
- If you can't do that either, build a custom item reader.

Here'a  [link](http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/) to browse the spring batch source code and check which Session version is being used when if you will start looking for item readers in various Spring Batch versions under the package  org.springframework.batch.item.

Comment: I completely agree, why would hibernate 3 uses classic `Session`!! thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is Simple. You can write your own HibernateItemReaderHelper  by simply changing the session type of original HibernateItemReaderHelper from Spring-Batch 2.2.7 RELEASE.below is the HibernateItemReaderHelper which will work with your Hibernate version. the original file was Extracted from Spring-Batch 2.2.7 RELEASE and customized to work with hibernate 3.2.5.GA

```
package com.baji.batch.readers;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.ScrollMode;
import org.hibernate.ScrollableResults;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.StatelessSession;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.orm.HibernateQueryProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * Internal shared state helper for hibernate readers managing sessions and
 * queries.
 *
 * @author Dave Syer
 *
 */
public class HibernateItemReaderHelper<T> implements InitializingBean {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private String queryString = "";

    private String queryName = "";

    private HibernateQueryProvider queryProvider;

    private boolean useStatelessSession = true;

    private StatelessSession statelessSession;

    private Session statefulSession;

    /**
     * @param queryName name of a hibernate named query
     */
    public void setQueryName(String queryName) {
        this.queryName = queryName;
    }

    /**
     * @param queryString HQL query string
     */
    public void setQueryString(String queryString) {
        this.queryString = queryString;
    }

    /**
     * @param queryProvider Hibernate query provider
     */
    public void setQueryProvider(HibernateQueryProvider queryProvider) {
        this.queryProvider = queryProvider;
    }

    /**
     * Can be set only in uninitialized state.
     *
     * @param useStatelessSession <code>true</code> to use
     * {@link StatelessSession} <code>false</code> to use standard hibernate
     * {@link Session}
     */
    public void setUseStatelessSession(boolean useStatelessSession) {
        Assert.state(statefulSession == null && statelessSession == null,
                "The useStatelessSession flag can only be set before a session is initialized.");
        this.useStatelessSession = useStatelessSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param sessionFactory hibernate session factory
     */
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

        Assert.state(sessionFactory != null, "A SessionFactory must be provided");

        if (queryProvider == null) {
            Assert.notNull(sessionFactory, "session factory must be set");
            Assert.state(StringUtils.hasText(queryString) ^ StringUtils.hasText(queryName),
                    "queryString or queryName must be set");
        }
        // making sure that the appropriate (Hibernate) query provider is set
        else {
            Assert.state(queryProvider != null, "Hibernate query provider must be set");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Get a cursor over all of the results, with the forward-only flag set.
     *
     * @param fetchSize the fetch size to use retrieving the results
     * @param parameterValues the parameter values to use (or null if none).
     *
     * @return a forward-only {@link ScrollableResults}
     */
    public ScrollableResults getForwardOnlyCursor(int fetchSize, Map<String, Object> parameterValues) {
        Query query = createQuery();
        if (parameterValues != null) {
            query.setProperties(parameterValues);
        }
        return query.setFetchSize(fetchSize).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    }

    /**
     * Open appropriate type of hibernate session and create the query.
     */
    public Query createQuery() {

        if (useStatelessSession) {
            if (statelessSession == null) {
                statelessSession = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
            }
            if (queryProvider != null) {
                queryProvider.setStatelessSession(statelessSession);
            }
            else {
                if (StringUtils.hasText(queryName)) {
                    return statelessSession.getNamedQuery(queryName);
                }
                else {
                    return statelessSession.createQuery(queryString);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (statefulSession == null) {
                statefulSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
            }
            if (queryProvider != null) {
                queryProvider.setSession(statefulSession);
            }
            else {
                if (StringUtils.hasText(queryName)) {
                    return statefulSession.getNamedQuery(queryName);
                }
                else {
                    return statefulSession.createQuery(queryString);
                }
            }
        }

        // If queryProvider is set use it to create a query
        return queryProvider.createQuery();

    }

    /**
     * Scroll through the results up to the item specified.
     *
     * @param cursor the results to scroll over
     */
    public void jumpToItem(ScrollableResults cursor, int itemIndex, int flushInterval) {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemIndex; i++) {
            cursor.next();
            if (i % flushInterval == 0 && !useStatelessSession) {
                statefulSession.clear(); // Clears in-memory cache
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the open session (stateful or otherwise).
     */
    public void close() {
        if (statelessSession != null) {
            statelessSession.close();
            statelessSession = null;
        }
        if (statefulSession != null) {
            statefulSession.close();
            statefulSession = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read a page of data, clearing the existing session (if necessary) first,
     * and creating a new session before executing the query.
     *
     * @param page the page to read (starting at 0)
     * @param pageSize the size of the page or maximum number of items to read
     * @param fetchSize the fetch size to use
     * @param parameterValues the parameter values to use (if any, otherwise
     * null)
     * @return a collection of items
     */
    public Collection<? extends T> readPage(int page, int pageSize, int fetchSize, Map<String, Object> parameterValues) {

        clear();

        Query query = createQuery();
        if (parameterValues != null) {
            query.setProperties(parameterValues);
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<T> result = query.setFetchSize(fetchSize).setFirstResult(page * pageSize).setMaxResults(pageSize).list();
        return result;

    }

    /**
     * Clear the session if stateful.
     */
    public void clear() {
        if (statefulSession != null) {
            statefulSession.clear();
        }
    }

}
```